# ggplot in R: how to set alignment individually on axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot in R that displays three labels on the x-axis. By default, these labels are centered. However, I am searching for a way to left-align the first label, center the second, and right-align the third label. The linked photo shows the exact result that I try to replicate. Any suggestions on how I can do this in R?

The label alignment I try to replicate.[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
qplot(100*1:3,1) + scale_x_continuous(breaks=100*c(1,2,3)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=c(0,0.5,1)))
```

Comment: Thank you, baptiste! I have spent almost two hours on this, so I appreciate your prompt answer.