# How do I move my axis labels to the side in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I want to set the x-axis label under the right corner of the plot, and the y-axis label to the left upper corner.

As an example of a plot, I made up this short piece of code:

```
#library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
data("titanic_train", package = "titanic")
titanic <- titanic_train

ggplot(data = titanic, aes(x = Fare)) + 
  geom_histogram() +
 xlab("Want this on right side")
```

**What I tried and what I want**
I found something that moves the whole y-axis to the right (scale_y_continuous(position = "right")) but not the x-label.
I also found how to move the numbers on the labels [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42066682/ggplot-in-r-how-to-set-alignment-individually-on-axis-labels)  but I want the axis name to move from centered to right.

I want something like this:
[image: plot with axis labels both centered]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by aligning the axis title to the right using `theme(axis.title = element_text(hjust = 1))` (or `axis.title.x` and `axis.title.y`):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(titanic)
data("titanic_train", package = "titanic")
titanic <- titanic_train

ggplot(data = titanic, aes(x = Fare)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  xlab("Want this on right side") +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(hjust = 1))
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I was so close with my last try, but didn't realise. ;)